# Tried making gel-type candy, it recrystalized as it cooled?

Tags: candy

I wasn't sure if it would work anyway, but I always used to love the tubes of squeeze candy you could get when I was a kid. I tried to make it by modifying a hard candy recipe. I boiled it for about ten minutes at about 220 degeees F.

I removed it from the heat, mixed in my flavoring, and it was pretty much the desired texture when it started cooling. I put it in a container on the counter overnight and it seems to have just returned to the state of its base ingredients? I'm not sure why this happened, or how to prevent it in the future. Any advice?

Comment: What do you mean by "boiled it for about ten minutes at about 220 degrees F"? Did you use a thermometer in the sugar solution? Soft ball stage for sugar is 235-240F...  So where did you get the number 220?

Comment: @catilja if I'm being honest I just made it up, and yes I used a thermometer in the solution.

Comment: Glycerin is often added to soften up hard candy recipes. @15-20%IIRC.

Answer (score 3):

Try using sugars that *even in concentrated and cold form do not crystallize much* - like honey, industrially or home made invert syrup, thick jam...

Answer (score 2):

I assume, you've used Table sugar or Sucrose, which is known to crystallize. And some even call it crystal sugar ;)

I don't know if your recipe calls for (and how much if any...), but you might find some acidity helping you prevent crystallization. A small amount of lemon juice would provide enough acidity to break down some of the sucrose into glucose and fructose which will prevent crystal formation.